# Passing short date in TextBox WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datetime, textbox

Hello I have a `dataGrid` that upon double click opens a new `Window` and populates some `TextBoxes` 
My issue is the `Textboxes` are showing date and time when I would like it to show the short date.

I have configured my SQL Server database to strictly `Date` and it shows the short date in the database, so I'm not sure why it's passing the `DateTime` in my `Textbox`.

Please Help!

Here is my code for Window 1:

```
        private void dtGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        // User double clicks on DataGrid Row
        // Open new Window
        // Populate selected textboxes with selected datarow
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        var windowToOpen = new Window1();

        if (gd != null)
        {
            // Textboxes
            windowToOpen.txt_RowRecrd.Text = row_selected["DSP_ID"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_revcls.Text = row_selected["RateType"].ToString();

            windowToOpen.Show();
       }
    }
```

Here is the XAML for one of my `TextBoxes` in Window 2:

```
                        <TextBox
                        x:Name="txt_DateResolved"
                        Width="110"
                        Height="26"
                        Margin="5,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Foreground="Black"
                        IsEnabled="True">
                    </TextBox>
```

Comment: What's the value of `row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString()` and what's the type of the `DATERSLVD` column in the database? Are you using SQL Server or something else?

Comment: @mm8 Yes I am using SQL Server and the column for DATERSLVD is set to `date` in my SQL Server database.

Comment: And the value is of `row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString()` is what?

Comment: It's a short date, so `2020-04-16` and the format is changed when it passes through the `TextBox` and I was having the same issue with my `DataGrid` but I was able to resolve that with some code for formatting using `AutoGeneratedColumns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in C# you don't have `Date` struct you have only [`DateTime` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8). In your case, you can format DateTime in the `ToString()` method. You should have an instance of DateTime and on it, you can invoke the following method:

```
dateTime.ToShortDateString()
```

or

```
dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yy")
```

Example:

```
if (row_selected["DATERSLVD"] != null)
{   
  DateTime dateTime;
  if (DateTime.TryParse(row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString(), out dateTime))
  {
      windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
  }
  else
  {
      windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = ""; //assign default value
  }
}
```

Comment: I apologize I'm fairly new to C# but do you mean to create a new `class` or use something like `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(); dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yy");` And I would but that under `IntInitializeComponent();`?

Comment: I mean something like this: `windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = DateTime.Parse(row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();`

Comment: I'm getting the following exception message `System.FormatException: 'String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'`

Comment: You should check if `row_selected["DATERSLVD"] != null` before you invoke above code. If this value is null you can set some default value.

Comment: I did `if (row_selected["DATERSLVD"] != null)` before invoking `windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = DateTime.Parse(row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();` and I'm getting the same exception message

Comment: You can use `DateTime.TryParse` method, please look at my answer again. I've added an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the `object` returned from the `DataRowView` to a `DateTime` and then use the `ToString` overload that accepts a format:

```
windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(row_selected["DATERSLVD"])
    .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You may also want to check for and handle `null` values:

```
windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = row_selected["DATERSLVD"] == DBNull.Value?
    string.Empty : Convert.ToDateTime(row_selected["DATERSLVD"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I am receiving the following exception `System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'`

Comment: @IanMark: This means that `row_selected["DATERSLVD"]` equals `DBNull`. Then it's certainly not appearing as a date. Anyway, see my edit.